# Problems with a show more/show less Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a show more/show less on comments. the aim obviously being to shorten and lengthen the comments made when a user clicks on the create links for the jquery.

problem i am having is that i have multiple comments and instead of the jquery code doing the show more/less function for every comment brought back from the database it only does it for the first comment brought from the database then duplicates itself and overwrites the other images.

What is the problem with this code and what is the fix?
Html/php:

```
<p class="product-comment">$comments->comment</p>
```

Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            var showmoreHtml = $(".product-comment").html();
            var showlessHtml = showmoreHtml.substr(0,400);
            if(showmoreHtml.length > 400){
                $(".product-comment").html(showlessHtml).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (...Show More)</a>");
            }else{
                $(".product-comment").html(showmoreHtml);
            }
            $("body").on("click", ".product-comment-more", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent(".product-comment").html(showmoreHtml).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-less'> (Show less)</a>")
            });
            $("body").on("click", ".product-comment-less", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                $(this).parent(".product-comment").html(showmoreHtml.substr(0,400)).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (...Show More)</a>")
            });

        });
```

Comment: You should use each function, here some docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: The issue is that you're using a selector which returns multiple items.   jQuery functions work differently when you have multiple items depending on the function - eg `.html()` will get the html of the first element, while `.html(text)` will set the html on all of them.     The easiest option is to have two divs, one with the long and one with the short and toggle them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i think should work:+

**EDITED**

I made a fix, now should work

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $.each( $(".product-comment"), function( key, value ) {

            var showmoreHtml = $(this).html();
            var showlessHtml = showmoreHtml.substr(0,5);
            if(showmoreHtml.length > 5){
                $(this).html(showlessHtml).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (...Show More)</a>");
            }else{
                $(this).html(showmoreHtml);
            }
            $(this).on("click", ".product-comment-more", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent(".product-comment").html(showmoreHtml).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-less'> (Show less)</a>");
            });
            $(this).on("click", ".product-comment-less", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent(".product-comment").html(showmoreHtml.substr(0,5)).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more'> (...Show More)</a>")
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

To achieve what you want, you never have to lose your reference $(this).
You do that with each function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".product-comment").each(function(){
        var showmoreHtml = $(this).html();
        var showlessHtml = showmoreHtml.substr(0,400);
        if(showmoreHtml.length > 400){
            $(this).html(showlessHtml).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more' data-desc='" + showmoreHtml +"'> (...Show More)</a>");
        }else{
            $(this).html(showmoreHtml);
        }
    });
        $("body").on("click", ".product-comment-more", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent(".product-comment").html($(this).attr("data-desc")).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-less' data-desc='" + $(this).attr("data-desc")+"'> (Show less)</a>")
        });
        $("body").on("click", ".product-comment-less", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $(this).parent(".product-comment").html($(this).attr("data-desc").substr(0,400)).append("<a href='' class='product-comment-more' data-desc='" + $(this).attr("data-desc")+"'> (...Show More)</a>")
        });
});
```

The reason it takes the last one it's because $(".product-comment") may be a QueryALLSelector by doing the .html() it returns only the first occurence of the class. To go over all the elements you need a each function.